# Kotlin problem: My spinner does not update

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGeyM.png)

```
    private fun updateCurrencySpinner() {
    // Update selected item form the currency spinner based on the country spinner
    val currency = when (serviceSpinner.selectedItemPosition) {
        0 -> 0
        1 -> 0
        2 -> 1
        3 -> 2
        else -> 0
    }
    currenciesSpinner.setSelection(currency)
}
```

[when i call the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW40A.png)

```
        countrySpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            updateCurrencySpinner()
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
    }
```

can someone tell me why my spinner does not update (I call this function every time I change the selected item)?

Comment: Please show code example wich doesn't work

Comment: Added the code direct into the question

Comment: Add more of your code. Are you calling `setSelection` after setting the adapter?

Comment: Updated the shared code

Comment: You should set position from you adapter

Comment: What do u mean, dont understand it ?

Comment: @KittenLS How to do that?

Comment: currenciesSpinner adapter is already filled with which values, it seems a problem in adapter, do you have default selected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call updateCurrencySpinner when countrySpinner changes, but you don't use the value of countrySpinner, instead you use the value of serviceSpinner.

So even if you call the method when countrySpinner changes, it does not actually change anything because the value of serviceSpinner is still the same.